# Grails find/read text from pdf file

Tags: pdf, grails, groovy

we are using grails 2.1.1 and we want to search for **contact numbers** from a uploaded **pdf** file. We have already done this with doc files but now we want to search and extract contacts from pdf file as well.
Is there any way to search and extract text from pdf files in grails.

Comment: Have you inspected the PDF files? How exactly are the contact numbers encoded therein? Uniformly or different from file to file? Maybe sometimes as part of included bitmaps?

Answer (score 1):

have you looked at [apache tika](http://tika.apache.org)?

it should handle both these formats and save you time handling each type separately